# Replace blank & null fields at the same time in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe "column" which has blank & NaN (nulls) at the same time. Now I want to replace the blank & NaN field with a string "No Data". Please give some guidance on the same. I am using Python Pandas.

My dataframe column -

```
Col1
----

NaN
New York
NaN
```

This is what I have tried -

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].replace(r'\s+', "No Data", regex=True)
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].replace(np.NaN, "No Data", regex=True)
```

My resultant column looks like -

```
Col1
----
No Data
No data
NewNo DataYork
No Data
```

Thanks.

Comment: When I am trying to write the dataframe to sql, it gives me the following error "TypeError: expecting unicode data"; even though the datatype of col is still an object. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 4):

filter the df to set the empty/blank entries to `NaN` and then fill these:

```
In [27]:    
​
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['',np.NaN,'New York',np.NaN]})
df
Out[27]:
       Col1
0          
1       NaN
2  New York
3       NaN
In [28]:

df.loc[df['Col1'].str.len() == 0, 'Col1'] = np.NaN
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].fillna('No Data')
df
Out[28]:
       Col1
0   No Data
1   No Data
2  New York
3   No Data
```

Comment: I think this is the most canonical method because of .fillna()

Comment: @EdChum - When I am trying to write the dataframe to sql, it gives me the following error "TypeError: expecting unicode data"; even though the datatype of col is still an object. Any suggestions please.

Comment: It means you may have some erroneous data, if it's not too many rows you could scan the output from `df['Col1''].unique()` or `df[df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str) == False)]` to see if any values are not `str`

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the start and end of the regex:

```
In [11]: df.replace('^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
Out[11]:
       Col1
0       NaN
1       NaN
2  New York
3       NaN

In [12]: df.replace('^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).fillna("No Data")
Out[12]:
       Col1
0   No Data
1   No Data
2  New York
3   No Data
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the values you want to replace in a dictionary to the `replace` function:

```
In [944]: x.head()
Out[944]: 
  ind1      ind2  value  identifier
0   EA  01/01/07  0.231          55
1   EA  01/01/07  0.511          56
2   EA  01/01/07  0.357          57
3   EA  01/02/07  0.091          55
4   EA  01/02/07  0.161          57

In [945]: x.head().replace({55:'N/A', 56:'FiftySix'}, axis=1)
Out[945]: 
  ind1      ind2  value identifier
0   EA  01/01/07  0.231        N/A
1   EA  01/01/07  0.511   FiftySix
2   EA  01/01/07  0.357         57
3   EA  01/02/07  0.091        N/A
4   EA  01/02/07  0.161         57
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's a `where`-based approach:

```
>>> df["Col1"] = df.Col1.where(df.Col1.str.strip().str.len() > 0, "No Data")
>>> df
       Col1
0   No Data
1   No Data
2  New York
3   No Data
```

This replaces anything which after stripping doesn't have a positive length with "No Data".  NaNs stay NaN, and so they don't have a positive length.

(I'm really bad at remembering regex syntax so I tend to use named methods instead.)

Comment: #DSM- When I am trying to write the dataframe to sql, it gives me the following error "TypeError: expecting unicode data"; even though the datatype of col is still an object. Any suggestions please.